Difference between "levenshtein" and "python levenshtein" packages?
I installed the levenshtein module from conda-forge.  I don't recall the exact command used, but it was likely something similar to conda install -c conda-forge PackageName.  I queried the package versions.  I see two packages with exactly the same version number:
(py39) C:\>conda list levenshtein$
# packages in environment at C:\Users\User.Name\AppData\Local\anaconda3\envs\py39:
#
# Name             Version          Build Channel
levenshtein        0.25.1  py39h99910a6_0 conda-forge
python-levenshtein 0.25.1    pyhd8ed1ab_0 conda-forge

The version matches what I could find online here and here.  I can also find both variations on GitHube, here, here, and here.
To try and get an idea of whether they are different, I used Cygwin's Bash to navigate to Conda environment folder /c/Users/User.Name/AppData/Local/anaconda3/envs/py39 and searched for files related to the packages:
$ find * -name '*levenshtein*' -print | xargs ls -l
  7270 Jun  7 17:13 conda-meta/levenshtein-0.25.1-py39h99910a6_0.json
  4564 Jun  7 17:13 conda-meta/python-levenshtein-0.25.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0.json
  3951 Jan 27  2023 Lib/site-packages/gensim/similarities/__pycache__/levenshtein.cpython-39.pyc
  4505 Jan 27  2023 Lib/site-packages/gensim/similarities/levenshtein.py
219136 Apr  7 12:12 Lib/site-packages/Levenshtein/levenshtein_cpp.cp39-win_amd64.pyd

I'm not sure how to interpret these findings.  Looking at the top 2 JSON files, I see possibly relevant selected lines
levenshtein-0.25.1-py39h99910a6_0.json
--------------------------------------
"extracted_package_dir": "C:\\Users\\User.Name\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3\\pkgs\\levenshtein-0.25.1-py39h99910a6_0",
"fn": "levenshtein-0.25.1-py39h99910a6_0.conda",
  "source": "C:\\Users\\User.Name\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3\\pkgs\\levenshtein-0.25.1-py39h99910a6_0",
"package_tarball_full_path": "C:\\Users\\User.Name\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3\\pkgs\\levenshtein-0.25.1-py39h99910a6_0.conda",

python-levenshtein-0.25.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0.json
-------------------------------------------
"extracted_package_dir": "C:\\Users\\User.Name\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3\\pkgs\\python-levenshtein-0.25.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0",
"fn": "python-levenshtein-0.25.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0.conda",
  "source": "C:\\Users\\User.Name\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3\\pkgs\\python-levenshtein-0.25.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0",
"package_tarball_full_path": "C:\\Users\\User.Name\\AppData\\Local\\anaconda3\\pkgs\\python-levenshtein-0.25.1-pyhd8ed1ab_0.conda",

Are the two packages in fact the same?  If so, why would they manifest as differently name packages?  How can one check whether a common package is made available via two different names?

Looking through the package indices for python-levenshtein leads us to https://github.com/rapidfuzz/python-Levenshtein, which says in the README:

⚠️ The package was renamed to Levenshtein and can be found here. The python-Levenshtein package will continue to be updated alongside the new package

So as it seems, they're the same package, with python-levenshtein being maintained for compatibility's sake.

Yup.  python-Levenshtein is an abandoned fork of Levenshtein

Not exactly abandoned, it seems like package releases are still going out, albeit with Levenshtein as the source - the python-Levenshtein repo isn't getting new commits but it's got new versions associated.

I was hoping to walk through your process for sleuthing this down.  Would you be able to elaborate on what piece of data you mean by "package indices"?  Is it from conda list, or in the JSON files?  I searched for "github" in the JSON files, but couldn't find any occurrence of it.  Thanks.

@user2153235 sure, if you just look on the Anaconda website and search python-levenshtein the package pops up (https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python-levenshtein) and you can see the upstream repo from within that page - in this case it points to maxbachmann/python-Levenshtein on GitHub, which redirects to rapidfuzz/python-Levenshtein as cited in my answer.

I am discovering my extreme ignorance of Anaconda. I went to anaconda.com, where one can swim around forever trying to find out how to search for packages. I then tried Anaconda Navigator and had the same luck (didn't try creating an account to connect to the cloud). Finally found anaconda.org, where (depending on the page), one has to tap the hamburger menu icon to access the search. Finally found my way to your citations above.  Thanks!
